# Android Studio: How to go to a certain url when clicking on a word in an array

Tags: android

I'm having trouble getting my android app to play a url when I click a button. I have an array of words declared as:

```
 // Create a list of words
 final ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();

words.add(new Word(R.string.family_mother, R.string.miwok_family_mother,
                R.drawable.family_mother, R.raw.family_mother));
words.add(new Word(R.string.family_son, R.string.miwok_family_son,
                R.drawable.family_son, R.raw.family_son));
```

I wanted to know if there was a way where inside each word in the array I could somehow pass in the url that I want called when I click on the button on the app. As of the right now if I click on each button it plays an audio since its referring to the audio tracks inside my raw directory. However I want my app to go to a certain url when clicked on a certain array.

Here's a url pic of my app:

https://ibb.co/iyhXgG

In the image depending on the word I click on will play an audio sound. I just don't know how to connect the url with each word in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define a string inside your word class to store url. Each instance of word will have a separate url string corresponding to each member.

Comment: Are you saying create an array of string inside my word class that holds a bunch of urls? Also how would I connect that to the other arrays of words I have so that I can go to the url based on the word I click on in the array?

Comment: no i'm not asking you to create an array of string. all you need is one string per word class. Consider this;
`words.add(new Word(R.string.family_son, R.string.miwok_family_son, R.string.your_action_URL, R.drawable.family_son, R.raw.family_son));`